# Big Query - Group By Clause not working with NEST()

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

Here is the reproduction on their public test data -

```
SELECT corpus, NEST(word) 
FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare] 
GROUP BY corpus 
LIMIT 1000
```

> Row   corpus          f0_
>      1    1kinghenryiv    brave
>      2    1kinghenryiv    profession
>      3    1kinghenryiv    treason

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing wrong
Per https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#aggfunctions

> BigQuery automatically flattens query results, so if you use the NEST
>   function on the top level query, the results **won't contain repeated
>   fields**. Use the NEST function when using a subselect that produces
>   intermediate results for immediate use by the same query.

Number of returning rows proves this (1000 in query  - but 41852 in result, because it is flattened:

[image]

You also can run below query to see that NEST() actually works:

```
SELECT corpus, COUNT(1) AS cnt 
FROM (
  SELECT corpus, NEST(word) 
  FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare] 
  GROUP BY corpus 
  LIMIT 1000
)
GROUP BY corpus
```

Comment: Note that you can preserve the repeated structure by writing to an output table and disabling the "flatten results" option.