# BigQuery creat repeated record field from query

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to create a repeated record column in BigQuery? For example, for the following data:

```
| a | b | c |
-------------
| 1 | 5 | 2 |
-------------
| 1 | 3 | 1 |
-------------
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
```

Is the following possible?

```
Select a, NEST(b, c) as d from *table* group by a
```

To produce the following results

```
| a | d.b | d.c |
-----------------
| 1 |  5  |  2  |
-----------------
|   |  3  |  1  |
-----------------
| 2 |  2  |  1  |
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the way to go around `NEST()` limitation of "nesting" just one field is to use [BigQuery User-Defined Functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/user-defined-functions). They are extremely powerful yet still have some [Limits](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/user-defined-functions#limits) and [Limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/user-defined-functions#limitations) to be aware of.  And most important from my prospective to have in mind  - they are quite a candidates for being qualified as expensive [High-Compute queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#high-compute)

> Complex queries can consume extraordinarily large computing resources
>   relative to the number of bytes processed. Typically, such queries
>   contain a very large number of JOIN or CROSS JOIN clauses or complex
>   User-defined Functions.

So, below is example that "mimic" NEST(b, c) from example in questino:

```
SELECT a, d.b, d.c FROM 
JS((      // input table
  SELECT a, NEST(CONCAT(STRING(b), ',', STRING(c))) AS d
  FROM (
    SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT 1 AS a, 5 AS b, 2 AS c),
    (SELECT 1 AS a, 3 AS b, 1 AS c),
    (SELECT 2 AS a, 2 AS b, 1 AS c)
  ) GROUP BY a),
  a, d,     // input columns
  "[{'name': 'a', 'type': 'INTEGER'},    // output schema
    {'name': 'd', 'type': 'RECORD',
     'mode': 'REPEATED',
     'fields': [
       {'name': 'b', 'type': 'STRING'},
       {'name': 'c', 'type': 'STRING'}
     ]    
    }
  ]",
  "function(row, emit){    // function 
    var c = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < row.d.length; i++) {
      x = row.d[i].toString().split(',');
      t = {b:x[0], c:x[1]}
      c.push(t);
    };
    emit({a: row.a, d: c});  
  }"
)
```

It is relatively straightforward. I hope you will be able to walk through it and get an idea

Still - remember:

> No matter how you create record with nested/repeated fields - BigQuery
>   automatically flattens query results, so visible results won't contain
>   repeated fields. So you should use it as a subselect that produces
>   intermediate results for immediate use by the same query.

As FYI, you can prove for yourself that above returns only two records (not three as it is looks like when it is flattened) by running below query

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS rows FROM (
  <above query here>
)
```

**Another important NOTE:**
This is a known that `NEST()` is not compatible with `UnFlatten Results` Output and mostly is used for intermediate result in subquery.
In contrast, above solution can be easily saved directly to table (with unchecked Flatten Results)

Answer (score 12):

With introduction of BigQuery Standard SQL we've got easy way to deal with records
Try below, *Don't forget to uncheck `Use Legacy SQL` checkbox under <kbd>Show Options</kbd>*

```
WITH YourTable AS (
  SELECT 1 AS a, 5 AS b, 2 AS c UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS a, 3 AS b, 1 AS c UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS a, 2 AS b, 1 AS c
)
SELECT a, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(b, c)) AS d
FROM YourTable 
GROUP BY a
```

Answer (score 0):

> BigQuery automatically flattens query results, so if you use the NEST
>   function on the top level query, the results won't contain repeated
>   fields. Use the NEST function when using a subselect that produces
>   intermediate results for immediate use by the same query.

See more about NEST() at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#aggfunctions

Also check [Big Query - Group By Clause not working with NEST()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34543058/big-query-group-by-clause-not-working-with-nest/34548568#34548568) as FYI

Another point to have in mind  - yo can NEST only one field - `NEST(b)` but not `NEST(b, c)`

That said - you can produce result similar to what you asked but you need to write it to the table

From my experience: users more facing this questions while loading data into BigQuery - that is were user can use nlJSON with as complex schema as needed.
In GBQ itself user usually more interested in analysis , aggregation so above type questions are rised less frequently. I think current GBQ sysntax is not friendly/flexible enough to generate data of "complex" hierarchical/nested schema and insert it into table all in GBQ only. Still, I think workarounds are possible but depends on specific use case

Comment: Nesting multiple field is what I am actually asking.

Comment: I think, unfortunately, `NEST(b)` is not supported now. Would be great! You can submit your proposals